# implementing jlabel by codes in an automated jFrame in netbeans 6.9

Tags: netbeans, jframe, jlabel

Hi
i'm new with java swing,i try a lot and do a lot of search but in vain.i want to display a jlabel(not by drag n drop but with codes) on an automated jFrame that i have already.well my code for my JLabel is as follows:
private JLabel la=new JLabel("Display label");

codes that i got during my search to dispaly in a jpanel was like follows:
jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
but it does not work.My jPanel1 was built by drag n drop with the name Jpanel1.

i even try this piece of code:
this.add(jLabel1)--
this.getContentPane().add(jLabel1)
but still not working.

Please help me,it must be a simple line of code or i'm missing something somewhere ,please..thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple piece of code obtained from [link text](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-tutorial)

```
public class HelloWorldFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new HelloWorldFrame();
    }
    HelloWorldFrame() {
        JLabel jlbHelloWorld = new JLabel("Hello World");
        add(jlbHelloWorld);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        // pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What you need to do is to re-set the `setVisible` property of the parent component to true

Comment: thx...but the frame has already been displayed automatically when i used the GUI netbeans6.9.how should i link my label(private JLabel jLabel1= newJLabel();)to that frame so that it display on the existing automated frame?

Comment: The piece of code I attached was just a sample that would guide you in the right direction. Did you try adding this.setVisible(true) after you add the jLabel to your panel?

Comment: yes i did but still it does not work...please help.During my search i see validate(),i have use that too but still not working.just a small comfirmation, for this.setVisible,the 'this' refer to the jframe,right?

Comment: 'this' refers to the current instance of the class. So if you are extending the JPanel in youy class, 'this' will give you access to the method that your class has inherited and extends. In the example I posted, 'this' will give you access to JFrame methods.

Comment: No probs. I suggest you mark this answer as correct. You should mark the answers we post, this will show whenever you ask questions in the future and will motivate other people to answer your questions. To mark an answer as correct, just click on the 'thick' near the answer

Comment: well i'm back.i can't position my jlabel to a specific position in my jpanel.i've use jlabel1.setposition(x,y) but still it has not change.the label is dispalyed at the top centered...y so?

Comment: If you want to have complete freedom over how and where your components are placed, you will have to do as follows:
yourJFrame.setLayout(null);

Comment: i tried it but it does not work.my codes are as follows: pan1.setBackground(Color.red);lab.setSize(80,90); pan1.setBounds(55, 110, 300, 100);lab.setLocation(100,120); pan1.add(lab);this.setContentPane(pan1);                                    the panel is being displayed at the desired position but the lab is not.it remain in the center of the panel.